Impact of geo-relevant backlink: Good or not really?
Looking at building some backlinks and have a question regarding the geographic relevancy.
We have a website intended primarily for an Australian audience. When it comes to improving DA / DR, do we target Australian only backlinks? Or they can they from anywhere in the world?
The reason why I ask is because we spoke to two experts with varying opinions: one suggested it doesn't, a quality backlink from the US is a quality backlink for example. Whereas another suggested we should only target backlinks from Australian websites.
I understand from a direct referral / direct traffic perspective, we would want Australian backlinks, but from the view of improving search results, does locality or audience of the backlink matter?

As a rule of thumb, you should aim to get backlinks from where your actual users are going to click them, otherwise it's just spam.  Relevant international backlinks from real sites should be fine, whereas irrelevant Austrialian backlinks aren't.

Simply put, both matter. The difference is that a link from the same country as yours adds to your Local Authority. So, if you want to rank higher locally, try to target more country-specific links to add to your local reputation.

The geo-relevant backlinks are more useful and powerful for local businesses. But more than that the relevancy of the website is more effective.
If you are getting a link from Australia but not very much relevant to your niche then it is better to get a link from the USA if that website is relevant to your niche.
Google counts the relevancy at the top.
